# Query to update multiple rows with existing data

Tags: sql

I have a table with latitude and longitude. It has millions of records and when I got the table, the google maps were pointing the location in middle of ocean and other weird places.
So, when I checked, those records had a .(period) in wrong place. So, could someone please tell me how to update those million records and update .(period) in all those records? I need to move period to third place from second for Longitude. So, instead of -66.722528, it should be -667.22528 for all million records.

Sample

Latitude    Longitude
18.164704   -66.722528

Comment: Is it always going to be 5 decimal places for longitude?

Comment: One of my record has Carmichael, CA.
In the table it has 38.6394, 12.13214 which is in middle of ocean near Portugal.
If I edit it like this 
38.6394° N, 121.3214° W, its Carmichael.
So instead of multiplying, I was wondering if there was a way to count the .(period) and move its place from second to third place without worrying about the numbers at end.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to multiply by 10.

Try something along the lines of:

```
update myTable set Longitude = Longitude * 10
```